# JSFiddle Code to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jsfiddle

The following works in JSFiddle, but when use it on my site it does not work.

http://jsfiddle.net/jazzviolin/g1t6y71n/

HTML

```
Event Date:<input type="text" id="date" />
<br />
Event Title:<input type="text" id="header" />
<br />
Description:<input type="text" id="desc"/>
<br />
URL for PDF:<input type="text" id="url_for_pdf" />
<br />
URL for Thumbnail Image:<input type="text" id="url_for_thumb" />
<br />
<button id="create-html">Get Code</button>

<div id="result"></div>
```

JS

```
$( "#create-html" ).click(function() {
var date = '<div class="singleevent"><p class="date">' + $("#date").val() + '</p>';
var header = '<p class="header">' + $("#header").val() + '</p>';
var desc = '<p class="desc">' + $("#desc").val() +'</p>';

var url_for_event = '<ul><li><a href="#"><img src="http://www.example.com/-/i/social-mail.png" width="17" height="13" alt=""/></a></li><li><a href="#"><img src="http://www.example.com/-/i/social-fb.png" width="17" height="13" alt=""/></a></li> <li><a href="#"><img src="http://www.example.com/-/i/social-twitter.png" width="16" height="13" alt=""/></a></li><li><a href="' + $("#url_for_pdf").val() +'"><img src="http://www.example.com/-/i/social-download.png" width="13" height="13" alt=""/></a></li></ul><span class="img"><a href="' + $("#url_for_pdf").val() +'"><img src="'+ $("#url_for_thumb").val() + '"" alt=""/></a></span></div>';

$( "#result" ).text(date + header + desc + url_for_event);
});
```

I realize others have pointed out the onLoad has to be turned to NoWrap - in , but I don't know how to convert the JS to work with a live site. I apologize in advance for my lack of JS knowledge, and I'm very thankful for you time.

Comment: what exactly is your problem? If the JS is evaluating `undefined`, then yes you should wrap it in a jQuery `ready()` function, see [here](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Comment: are you including the script between the `<head></head>` tag already? `<script src="yourscript.js"></script>`

Comment: Go to http://jsfiddle.net/jazzviolin/g1t6y71n/show/ , take a look at the source, that's what has been rendered based on the contents of your fiddle.

Comment: Do you have jQuery included in your web page?

Comment: +1 for jsfiddle's `/show`, which I did not know about!

Comment: Look my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25212560/jsfiddle-code-to-html/25212674#25212674 :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all don't forget to include jQuery, since you are using it in your JS.

Then you can just include you JS right into your HTML page inside `<script></script>` tags

Answer (score 0):

I see there is a jQuery dependency; maybe you need to add that into the HTML?

https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Any javascript in an HTML file should be wrapped in `<script></script>` tags. In addition, you'll need to include the jQuery library since it looks like you're using that, and probably wrap your code in a `$(document).ready() or similar.`

I suggest you start learning the very basics of "installing" / using jQuery here: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_install.asp

Answer (score 0):

From what it looks like, do you have your script tags in the HTML side of things that references your JS code?

Put that function in a .js file, reference it via `<script></script>` tags in the HTML document so it can be integrated and used.

And use the proper jQuery libraries at the top of your HTML document. It looks like you are getting there and have the right functionality/idea but you need to import these things for it to work when being run.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you included the jQuery library. In your fiddle you are using 2.1, so try including jQuery 2.1 into your .html file   like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look if you have something like this and fix what you can have wrong

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="yourscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    Event Date:<input type="text" id="date" />
    <br />
    Event Title:<input type="text" id="header" />
    <br />
    Description:<input type="text" id="desc"/>
    <br />
    URL for PDF:<input type="text" id="url_for_pdf" />
    <br />
    URL for Thumbnail Image:<input type="text" id="url_for_thumb" />
    <br />
    <button id="create-html">Get Code</button>
    <div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**yourscript.js**

```
$( "#create-html" ).click(function() {
    var date = '<div class="singleevent"><p class="date">' + $("#date").val() + '</p>';
    var header = '<p class="header">' + $("#header").val() + '</p>';
    var desc = '<p class="desc">' + $("#desc").val() +'</p>';

    var url_for_event = '<ul><li><a href="#"><img src="http://www.example.com/-/i/social-mail.png" width="17" height="13" alt=""/></a></li><li><a href="#"><img src="http://www.example.com/-/i/social-fb.png" width="17" height="13" alt=""/></a></li> <li><a href="#"><img src="http://www.example.com/-/i/social-twitter.png" width="16" height="13" alt=""/></a></li><li><a href="' + $("#url_for_pdf").val() +'"><img src="http://www.example.com/-/i/social-download.png" width="13" height="13" alt=""/></a></li></ul><span class="img"><a href="' + $("#url_for_pdf").val() +'"><img src="'+ $("#url_for_thumb").val() + '"" alt=""/></a></span></div>';

    $( "#result" ).text(date + header + desc + url_for_event);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to take a fiddle and convert it to an HTML document, the easiest way is to right-click on the `Output` frame and view the frame source (depending on the browser it may be different; on Chrome it's `View Frame Source`).

This should bring up the actual source that you can copy + paste into an .html document. Although you'll probably need to remove the line `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo by jazzviolin</title>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js'></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">

  <style type='text/css'>

  </style>



<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$( "#create-html" ).click(function() {
    var date = '<div class="singleevent"><p class="date">' + $("#date").val() + '</p>';
    var header = '<p class="header">' + $("#header").val() + '</p>';
    var desc = '<p class="desc">' + $("#desc").val() +'</p>';

    var url_for_event = '<ul><li><a href="#"><img src="http://www.example.com/-/i/social-mail.png" width="17" height="13" alt=""/></a></li><li><a href="#"><img src="http://www.example.com/-/i/social-fb.png" width="17" height="13" alt=""/></a></li> <li><a href="#"><img src="http://www.example.com/-/i/social-twitter.png" width="16" height="13" alt=""/></a></li><li><a href="' + $("#url_for_pdf").val() +'"><img src="http://www.example.com/-/i/social-download.png" width="13" height="13" alt=""/></a></li></ul><span class="img"><a href="' + $("#url_for_pdf").val() +'"><img src="'+ $("#url_for_thumb").val() + '"" alt=""/></a></span></div>';

    $( "#result" ).text(date + header + desc + url_for_event);
});
});//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>
  Event Date:<input type="text" id="date" />
<br />
Event Title:<input type="text" id="header" />
<br />
Description:<input type="text" id="desc"/>
<br />
URL for PDF:<input type="text" id="url_for_pdf" />
<br />
URL for Thumbnail Image:<input type="text" id="url_for_thumb" />
<br />
<button id="create-html">Get Code for WordPress</button>

<div id="result"></div>

</body>


</html>
```